# How to implement nested queryset in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

I am building API from django rest framework. I have a model in which there are certain foreign keys. For that model listing I am using ListAPIView. In that listing I want to implement nested queryset. Foreign key models are not directly in relation with each other.
In following example. 
For multiple x there can be multiple y 
and for multiple y there can be multiple z.
So I want json response as for unique x and in that object its y and its z.

I tried with annotate and subquery. But that does not seem to solve my issue.

```
Table: 
|x_id | y_id | z_id |
|1    | 2    | 3    |
|1    | 4    | 5    |
|1    | 2    | 6    |
```

```py
class Workitem(models.Model):
{ 
  x_id = # foreign key
  y_id = # foreign key
  z_id = # foreign key
}
class x(models.Model):
{ 
  x_id = 
  x_name = 
  x_details = 
}
class y(models.Model):
{ 
  y_id = 
  y_unique_name = 
  y_task_details = 
}
class z(models.Model):
{ 
  z_id = 
  z_acc_name = 
  z_acc_details = 
}
```

```py
class WorkitemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
            model = Workitem
            fields = '__all__'
            depth=2
```

Current I am getting JSON response a

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results":
       [
        { "x_id": {"x_details"},
          "y_id": {"y_details"},
          "z_id": {"z_details"}
        }
       ]
}
```

I want response as

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
     results: ["x_id":{
                       "x_details":
                        "y_id": {
                                 "y_details":
                                 "z_id": {
                                         "z_details":
                                         }
                                },
                       },
                ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that sort of a response you need to make chain the serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class zserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)

      class Meta:
          model = zModel
          fields = '__all__'

class yserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
      zobjects = zserializer(many=True)
      class Meta:
          model = yModel
          fields = ('id', 'zobjects')


class xserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
      yobjects = yserializer(many=True)
      class Meta:
          model = xModel
          fields = ('id', 'yobjects')
```

Then in the view use the xserializer for listing.
Let us know if this solves your query.

Comment: Initially I thought the same . But this can be done only when yModel is foreign key in xModel and so on for yModel and zModel.  For me that is not the case. yModel and xModel are not in relation.  So what can be done in this case ? and thanks for details.

Comment: Can you please post your models.

Comment: From models ,u posted, i am not able to guess how x and y are  related and son on. There is no field in y models which defines its relationship to x. In such a situation we can not nest y's with x and so on. If this is not the case, are we missing something in the models ?

Comment: That is exactly my case ! There is no field in y model which defines its relationship to x. still I want do to nesting ! Can I do that ? Any workaround?

Comment: I dont know a workaround for this and i dont think its possible with that model structure. For the type of output you want, you need to have foreignkey relationship in your models.

Comment: I can't create foreignkey in models. Thanks for your response,